# Error unknown type name 'ofstream'

Tags: c++, fstream

siempre he hecho declaraciones como las que muestro en el código de abajo, sin embargo hoy me está dando un error que nunca me ha salido y no veo mi fallo.

**File.h**

```
#ifndef FILE_H
#define FILE_H

#include <fstream>
#include <Client.h>

class File
{
public:
    File();
    void addClient(Client client);
};

#endif // FILE_H
```

**File.cpp**

```
#include "File.h"

File::File()
{

}

void File::addClient(Client client)
{
    ofstream fileOut("Clients.bin", ios::binary | ios::app);
    fileOut.write(client);
    fileOut.close();
}
```

y el error es el siguiente:
***error: unknown type name 'ofstream'***

Gracias de antemano :)

Comment: Si no haces `using namespace std;`, entonces tienes que cualificarlo por completo: `std::ofstream fileOut( ... )`.

Answer (score 2):

El objeto `ofstream` está en el espacio de nombres `std`, por lo tanto tienes estas opciones:

1. Cualificar el nombre al completo:

   ```
   void File::addClient(Client client)
   {
       std::ofstream fileOut("Clients.bin", ios::binary | ios::app);
   //  ^^^^^ <--- Espacio de nombres std.
       fileOut.write(client);
       fileOut.close();
   }
   ```
2. Añadir al ámbito el espacio de nombres:

   ```
   void File::addClient(Client client)
   {
       using namespace std;
   /*  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- Todo lo perteneciente a 'std::' se podrá usar sin
                                 añadir el espacio de nombres en este ámbito */

       ofstream fileOut("Clients.bin", ios::binary | ios::app);
       fileOut.write(client);
       fileOut.close();
   }
   ```

### Otras cosas a tener en cuenta

- Si la definición de tu constructor está vacía:

  ```
    File::File()
    {

    }
  ```

  ¡No lo declares! O valora marcar la declaración como `default` para que la definición la haga el compilador:

  ```
    class File
    {
    public:
        File() = default; // No es necesaria definición, se encargará el compilador.
        void addClient(Client client);
    };
  ```
- Si un objeto sólo se usa en el archivo de código (`*.cpp`) no hagas la inclusión en el archivo de cabecera, es decir: mueve `#include <fstream>` de `File.h` a `File.cpp`.